# margin: 0 auto; does not work in Chrome on body tag

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging, margin

I encountered a serious bug in Chrome today which involves the CSS margin property on the body element. As you know, when applying `margin: 0 auto;` along with a width to the body element, the site is centered and it worked for me all the time. However, today this suddenly stopped working for me in Chrome (newest version 36.0.1985.125 m).

Now, many websites use `margin: 0 auto;` on a container div which is why not every site is affected, but those which use it on the body tag are shifted to the left because they are not centered anymore. More precisely, the site looks normal for a fraction of a second and then the whole body starts moving to the left.

I made [a little demo](http://codepen.io/timwagner/full/lCAgv/) here and in case you don't see the bug, here is a screenshot of what the site looks to me [on Chrome](http://www11.pic-upload.de/04.08.14/4funlgy3367.png). It works on Firefox.

I researched a little bit and I did not find anything. The bug appears to be only visible for me. I did not install any plugins which could cause the bug.

So, my question is: Do you know about the bug, can you see it too and how can I fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Works fine for me and I have the same version of Chrome. Are you sure there is nothing else interfering?

Comment: Works for me with Version 36.0.1985.125 on Mac OS X.

Comment: Have you tried applying `display: block;` to your body tag?

Comment: `ctrl` + `shift` + `n`. Does it work in incognito mode? i.e. with most extensions disabled?

Comment: may also have to apply style to the HTML tag as well, why you are trying to center the body element itself is beyond me, a properly formatted site should be wrapped in a div then the div should be centered in the body.

Comment: @misterManSam Indeed it does work in incognito mode. I looked over my extentions and I found one called flowsurf which might have installed along with another program and a quick google search proved it is a virus. I deinstalled it and it works again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, an extention seemed to have caused the bug. It is called Flowsurf and it installed along with another program. Didn't notice it! So everything's all right with Chrome, it was just the extention that caused it.